# How are mouse events propagated in QGraphicsView, scene and item?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsView` on which there is a `QGraphicsScene` on which there are `QGraphicsRectItem`.

For each of these 3 classes, I've implemented `mousePressEvent()`.

Now, I would want to know what happens when we click. Does the event first go to view, then to scene, then to item?

Can you please explain in detail about how mouse clicks are handled for each of these 3 classes?

I have already implemented `eventFilter` for `QGraphicsView` to support zoom and pan functionalities.

Example:

In the image below, I would want to get the innermost green rectangle (with text 230, 30) when I click on it...

[image]

Comment: You can easily write a test case that will show the order of event processing, but of course, the event goes to a widget first, and then goes to the scene, and then to any more specific items if they are interested. View-specific functionality must be implemented in the view. Remember that there can be many views on any scene, and you wouldn't want the zoom/pan in one to affect others unless you explicitly need such behavior; but even then you wouldn't want to mess with the scene, but just propagate some of the view's state across many views.

Comment: @KubaOber : I think you wrote incorrect : "Remember that there can be many views on any scene"  ... It should be that multiple scenes can be added to single view....

Comment: @KubaOber : I wrote a test application and I saw that the events are sent in reverse order of what you mentioned : even first came to the rect item, then to scene and then to view.... Pls check and confirm.

Comment: "multiple scenes can be added to single view" That's incorrect. A view can display one scene at a time.

Comment: Can't confirm anything without seeing your code.